# Should I normalize DB table when in 97.4% of the cases it would lead to 1:1 relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, relational-database, database-schema

I have a database table of trading card game cards. There are about 19 000 cards/rows with different names, but about 500 (2.6%) of them share functionality with another card(s). These cards (and their functionalities) may have a better-worse relationship with each other. The better-worse relationship can also be given points, so it makes sense to create the better-worse relation based on card' functionality, so the points are shared between different card names that happen to share functionality. I may also expand on the better-worse relation, so a future proof solution should be used.

An example:
Cards A and B have the same functionality. Both are worse than card C. If I want to give points to A->C relationship, it makes sense I want to give points to B->C relationship too.

However, if I separate the card functionality to a different table from the main cards table, 18 500 (97.6%) of the rows will have a 1:1 relationship with the new functionalities table, while the rest, 500 (2.6%) will have n:1. Is this bad design and should I find another way? Is 1:1 warranted in this case?

Alternatively I could create table for the 500 "special" cases and have programming logic decide whether to use that table to create the better-worse relation or the individual cards table. I'm not too sure if I can sufficiently abstract the difference away in programming logic, so that I won't shoot myself in the foot in future.

Third option would be to just copy the points to each relationship as needed (in a transaction for integrity). This is probably the least maintainable way. Any new features would also need to be copied in some way.

Comment: I see nothing wrong with option 1 with many 1:1 relationships in this case. Option 2 sounds like a silly "optimization" that will save you a couple KBs in exchange for a couple headaches down the road and dirty business logic on the way. Forget option 3 for the reason you stated yourself. That said, at 20k records (easily fitting in memory): does it even matter?

Comment: None of this involves normalization. Normalization to higher NFs replaces a table by projections of it.

Comment: "Should" is to strong a word.  You "could", but you do not "have to".